# Seeking C/C++ equivalent of gdal2tiles.py?

Tags: gdal, software-recommendations

Is anyone aware of a permissively licenced open source C/C++ equivalent of gdal2tiles.py?

Want to generate OSM compatible tile sets from geo-referenced raster files, and have already confirmed that gdal2tiles.py will produce the output I need.

Am targeting a yocto generated embedded linux platform with relatively limited resources, so:

- Want a native library or command line executable, rather than something that involves dragging in the 400lb gorilla of a python interpreter/JVM/etc.
- Need something for which the source is available so I can cross-compile.

Am already aware of:

- [maptiler](https://www.maptiler.com/)  Commercial tiling tool which I believe was created by by the original authors of the gdal2tiles.
- [mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) Whole lot of stuff I don't need
- [simple-tiles](http://propublica.github.io/simple-tiles/).  Maybe, (haven't actually tried it yet) but note that it has a couple of extra dependencies above and beyond GDAL which I don't think I fundamentally need
- [gdalsplit](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/1566) A patch that has been sitting in the GDAL bug tracker for 10 years or more (effectively superseded by gdal2tiles I think).  Looking at source it appears to generate a simple tile grid with no depth, rather than the image pyramid  expected in an OSM/TMS tile set, but a useful reference.

Not too daunted by the prospect of mashing up my own implementation based on gdal2tiles & gdalsplit, or perhaps trying a compiled derivative of gdal2tiles using cython or whatever, but just wanted to confirm that there wasn't an existing solution somewhere out there that my google-fu had failed to identify

Comment: Have you considered to put the tiles into MBTiles or GeoPackage instead?

Comment: Yeah, am aware that gdal_translate will do that directly.  

I'm developing with Qt and at this point was planning on using the Qt Location `Map` component, for which the OSM plugin can be configured to work directly with a local offline tile directory, rather than running a local tile server.

Comment: For software recommendations I recommend the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.